# php generated table using rowspan

Tags: php, html-table

I am using this code to generate a table which will subsequently be modified to upload data to a mysql database.

```
<?php
$start_loc_number= 1 ;
$start_loc_alpha= 'A' ;
$end_loc_number= 10 ;
$end_loc_alpha= 'J' ;

$out = ''; 

   $out .= '<table border = 1 bordercolor="#FF0000">';

    for($tr='A';$tr<=$end_loc_alpha;$tr++)
    { $out .= "<tr>";
        for($td=1;$td<=$end_loc_number;$td++)
        { $out .= '<td BGCOLOR="#99CCFF">'.$tr.$td.'</td>

                                 <td id="sampleID" contenteditable="true">  sampleID</td>
                                 <td id="volume" contenteditable="true">  volume</td>'  ;
        }
    $out .= "</tr>";
    }

    $out .= "</table>";

echo $out; 
?>
```

At the moment the table generates 3 cells per iteration in 3 column cells,

```
| coordinates | sample ID | volume |
```

My question relates to how the php code can be altered so to generate a table where the coordinates cell can be arranged as a rowspan over the sampleID and volume cells positioned in 2 rows with the sample ID over the volume cell

```
|             | sample ID
| coordinates |------------
|             | volume
```

Comment: why don't you make a table with two row inside your td ?

Comment: that's what I've tried but have had no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
for($tr='A';$tr<=$end_loc_alpha;$tr++)
    { $out .= "<tr>";
        for($td=1;$td<=$end_loc_number;$td++)
        { $out .= '<td BGCOLOR="#99CCFF">'.$tr.$td.'</td><td>
                                <table><tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid red">
                                 <td id="sampleID" contenteditable="true">  sampleID</td></tr>
                                <tr> <td id="volume" contenteditable="true">  volume</td></tr></table></td>'  ;
        }
    $out .= "</tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">test</td>
        <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vg3nzea8/)

Comment: thanks but I was inquiring about the code rather than the HTML per se +1 in any case

Answer (score 1):

you can set `rowspan="2"` on your coords TD.

You really should not build your output like that. 
Try this approach:

```
<?php

$content = array(
    array(
        'cords' => 1,
        'samp' => "Bar",
        'vol' => 13
    ),
    array(
        'cords' => 2,
        'samp' => "Foo",
        'vol' => 456
    ),
    array(
        'cords' => 3,
        'samp' => "DJ",
        'vol' => 34
    )
);

?>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <? foreach($content as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Coordinates: <?= $value['cords'] ?></th>
            <td>sample ID: <?= $value['samp'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>volume: <?= $value['vol'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <? } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```